# What workflow can I use on to extract cartesian coordinates of many molecules from both .spartan and .out (Gaussian) files?

Tags: cheminformatics

I'm searching for a workflow for extracting cartesian coordinates for multiple moelcules from both a single file (e.g., several conformers from one .spartan file or one multiple molecules, each from multiple Gaussian output files). Any insight would be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu (14- & 16.04), on a machine on which I do not have either Gaussian or Spartan installed.

Thank you kindly

Comment: Hello. The common approach is invert some minutes in codding a simple script (using bash, python, perl, for example). It can be done in less than 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tool that I know for reading Spartan files (besides Spartan) is [Jmol](http://jmol.org/). With some programming or scripting, you will probably be able to save conformers to other files in a workflow - I don't think there is a pre-existing script.

There are multiple open source tools that read Gaussian output files. I would suggest either:

- [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/) - GUI, command-line and Python
- [cclib](http://cclib.github.io/) - using Python

For example to extract a bunch of Gaussian files to XYZ Cartesian:

`obabel *.log -oxyz -m`

The `-m` flag indicates "multiple" and the `-oxyz` indicates that you want XYZ-format files. More is in the [manual](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/).